# "SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal' using Tweepy with an academic access

Tags: twitter, tweepy

Very recently I got an academic access to Twitter API and I would like to start getting some data. Unfortunately, when I run the code I keep getting: "SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal'. It looks that something it is wrong with my bearer token.

In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQEsIs9LERM&t=7s, I found the following code:

[image]
also here: at n.3 https://github.com/jdfoote/Intro-to-Programming-and-Data-Science/blob/fall2021/extra_topics/twitter_v2_example.ipynb

Unfortunately, every time I try to run the code I got an error that points to the number after the % in my bearer token. One example here:

[image]

I tried to regenerate the bearer token multiple times by with no avail. Also, the definition of invalid decimal literal that I found on the internet doesn't seem to help. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance for your time!

Ps. sorry for including the image but the website kept rejecting the indentation of the code.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was banal: it works just adding the quotation marks to the bear token.